# Comparison Circles algorithm in Python

Tags: t-test, data-visualization, t-distribution, tukey-hsd-test

My goal is to visually represent similarities between groups using the comparison circles algorithm described here: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-analyst/7.10.1/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire-analyst_UsersGuide/box/box_comparison_circles_algorithm_.htm

Which seems to be based on Tukey's range test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test

I'm very, very stuck on calculating $q$... could I have a straightforward walkthrough on what needs to be done to get that value?

There seems to be multiple definitions of $q$ from the wikipedia page and the other documentation, as well as $q*$.

I'm also unclear what '$n_i$' means for calculating the radius - is that just the number of samples in the group? Same as '$n_j$'? '

EDIT: small progress. I did find this: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.stats.multicomp.get_tukeyQcrit.html

Comment: I have been searching for this as well, to replicate JMP's plot that sounds like what you describe.